# how to size row to fit with datagridview size in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Can someone please help me get the `DataGridView` to keep the rows fit size to `DataGridView` although there is a few rows. I mean rows size will change like `AutoSizeColumnMode` Propeties' Fill.

Answer (score 1):

There is similarly an [`AutoSizeRowsMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autosizerowsmode.aspx)

The value should be one of the ENUMs provided in the [`DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewautosizerowsmode.aspx) class.